# Selection of at least one vowel and one consonant

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, permutations, combinations

> Find the number of ways of selection of atleast one vowel and one consonant from the word TRIPLE.

Attempt:

We have $(I,E)$ and $(T,R,P,L)$

We choose $\dbinom{2}{1} \times \dbinom{4}{1}\times 2^4$

Explanation of attempt:

First choose one vowel.

Then choose one consonant.

Then the rest have 2 choices each - to be selected or not.

Why is my method incorrect?

(The answer is $45$)

Comment: Because the first vowel and consonant in the way you choose is "special" while it doesn't need to.

Comment: I don't get you @user202729

Comment: they said at least...

Comment: @XcoderX that is why there are 2 choices for each of the remaining ones.

Comment: The qn didnt specfiy the number of letters to choose....

Comment: @XcoderX Yes...I know that...Please see that it can be two letters too when none other letter is selected... 2 gives choice for each letter.It includes possibility when none of the four remaining ones are selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose one vowel or two vowels ( so j goes from 1 to 2) and take also one consonant or more so i (number of consonants) goes from 1 to 4. So we have :

$$1\le j\le 2$$
$$1\le i\le 4$$

$$P=\sum_{j=1}^2\binom 2 j \sum_{i=1}^4\binom 4 i=(\binom 2 1 +\binom 2 2 ) \sum_{i=1}^4\binom 4 i=3\sum_{i=1}^4\binom 4 i=3*15=45$$

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a simpler way of seeing this than the existing answers: you need to pick a non-empty subset of $\{I, E\}$ and a non-empty subset of $\{T,R,P,L\}$. A set of $n$ elements has $2^n - 1$ non-empty subsets, so the solution is $(2^2 - 1)(2^4 - 1) = 3 \times 15 = 45$.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are 6 letters, the total number of possible ways is $2^6=64$

We can simplify the question by finding the ways that fail:  All consonants or all vowels.  All consonants is $2^4=16$.  All vowels is $2^2=4$.

Therefore, total number of ways is $64-(16+4–1)=45$.

In your attempt, you count the possibilities.  However, notice that you have repeated answers.  If the question asks for 2 letters, 1 vowel and 1 consonant, it is simply $^2C_1*^4C_1$.  However, you can choose more letters here.  You can choose another set of vowel and consonant.  Now that repeats.

Comment: Okay, @Abcd, I have edited to answer your query.  Does it help now?

Answer (score 0):

Lets break down the problem.

We need to find the number of ways of selecting at least 1 vowel and 1 consonant.

We have two vowels.

So we can select one vowel or  two vowels.

This can be done in 2C1 + 2C2 = 2 + 1 = 3 Ways.

We have 4 consonants.

We can select 1,2,3 or 4 Consonants.

4C1 + 4C2 + 4C3 + 4C4 = 4 + 6 + 4 + 1 = 15 Ways.

Number of ways of selecting at least one vowel and one consonant is 3 * 15 = 45.